# How to set body data indy HTTPS post

Tags: delphi, https, http-post, indy

So I've looked around, and the only question describing my problem is 6 years old with 0 answers, so I guess I will try again.

I am using delphi 2009 with Indy10.

I am trying to post `JSON` to an api using HTTPS.

```
Instance.FHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
Instance.FHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Instance.FHTTP);

{$IFDEF DEBUG}
Instance.FHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8888;
Instance.FHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
{$ENDIF}

Instance.FHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
Instance.FAccessToken := Instance.FHTTP.Post('https://somedomain.com/api/endpoint', '{JSONName: JSONValue }' );
```

I have seen many answers suggesting that the `JSON` payload should be given as a `string` param in the `TidHTTP.Post`method, but when i try that, it expects a filepath, and throws an error saying:

> 'Cannot open file "[path to project{JSONName:JSONValue }]". The specified file was not found'.

If i add my `JSON` to a `TStringList` and add give that as a parameter, it simply adds the JSON to the header of the request.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*I have seen many answers suggesting that the JSON payload should be given as a string param*" - such examples are wrong, and I'm surprised anyone would have made that mistake in the first place given the param name is `ASourceFile`. "*If i add my JSON to a TStringList and add give that as a parameter, it simply adds the JSON to the header of the request.*" No it doesn't. It formats the `TStringList` data in the POST body using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Post` overload that takes a second string indeed interprets it as a filename:

```
function Post(AURL: string; const ASourceFile: String): string; overload;
```

That's why this doesn't work. You need to instead use the overload that takes a `TStream`:

```
function Post(AURL: string; ASource: TStream): string; overload;
```

You can put your JSON in a `TStringStream`:

```
StringStream := TStringStream.Create('{JSONName: JSONValue }', TEncoding.UTF8);
try
  Instance.FAccessToken := Instance.FHTTP.Post('https://somedomain.com/api/endpoint', StringStream);
finally
  StringStream.Free;
end;
```